# ¿Se puede prender una pc con python?

Tags: python

Estoy trabajando en un software con el lenguaje python, donde tengo que poner una opción donde el usuario pueda encender su pc desde otra que tenga el software. Queria saber si se puede hacer desde python, o si se puede desde otro lenguaje y si es asi como puedo conectarlo con python asi se ejecuta cuando el usuario apreta la opción.

Comment: Entiendo que estás buscando implementar la funcionalidad Wake On Lan (WOL) desde Python https://github.com/remcohaszing/pywakeonlan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La única manera en la que sería factible esto es configurando [Wake on LAN](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake_on_LAN), pero tiene la limitación de que la computadora que quiere encender a la otra necesita estar en en la misma red local o abrir puertos (port forwarding) para que pueda recibir paquetes de afuera (lo cual puede llegar a ser peligroso).

En mayoría de sistemas operativos es algo nativo que se puede configurar (aunque depende tambien de soporte de la placa de red). Luego, puedes usar el modulo `wakeonlan` (lo puedes instalar con pip usando `pip install wakeonlan`).

Usando una MAC de la PC que quieres encender, puedes hacer esto para intentar encender la PC que quieres:

```
from wakeonlan import send_magic_packet

send_magic_packet('ff.ff.ff.ff.ff.ff')
```

También se pueden usar IPs, encontrarás documentación aquí: https://pypi.org/project/wakeonlan/

Aunque existen otras maneras, estas requieren hardware adicional o específico. Wake on LAN es la implementación mas genérica que hay por ahí.

Comment: favor de no responder a preguntas tan amplias que no muestran avance o investigación